# Django front end site wide actions

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Is there a way that I can list, by author, and by activity (what kind, like posted a message, created a new file,etc) in the frontend of my site? kind of like a news of the site activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`django-activity-stream`](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream) might do the job

Comment: Confirmed, this is a fantastic app.